# Why use the name 'op_Addition' for operator '+' rather than the name '+'?

Tags: c#, cil

When you overload an operator, such as `operator +`, the compiled CIL looks something like this:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static bool op_Addition(...) { ... }
```

Why use the name `op_Addition` here and not, say, the name `+`?

I'm suggesting that the CIL syntax should have been

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static bool +(...) { ... }
```

And the member name, when looking for it, would have been `+` rather than `op_Addition`.

Note: This is a question about language design; "because the spec says so" is not a helpful answer.

Comment: "because the spec says... nvm I would guess that op_Addition is easier to parse then +.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you suggest that it be called `+` instead. Simply saying "it should have been `+`" is as unhelpful as me saying "because the spec says so".

Comment: @BoltClock: Because the operator is `+`, not `op_Addition`. It's more natural to call it `+`. Surely, the designers had reasons for that, I'm just wondering what these reasons could have been.

Comment: My quess is that since op_addition is actually just another method taking 2 inputs of a specific type and returning a third, it is more convenient to call it like this. Check the generated CIL  for both an addition of 2  ints and an addition of 2 custom structs with a custom + operator implementation. The first will simply call the CIL instruction for adding ints, the latter will call a method

Comment: Thinking that "+" is a good name is biased, a Cobol programmer will disagree.  And will give you a headache when you need to come up with the name of the unary + operator overload.  The job of a spec writer is to make everybody equally unhappy.

Comment: @HansPassant: A unary `+` should also be called `+`. That's what overloading is for...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you named the method `+`, then only languages which supported operator overloading, or which allowed `+` as an identifier, would be able to call the underlying method.

The Unicode standard [defines a syntax for identifiers](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-18.html) in programming languages (see Annex 7), which is adopted by the [CLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx) for the identifier rules, does not include `+` in that syntax. Since most languages with support for Unicode identifiers will adhere to that syntax, it is unreasonable to expect such languages to allow `+` as an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

The CLR does not know about operators, so the c# compiler generates methods with thes special names so that other .net languages that do not have support for operators can consume them as methods.

[CLR Via c#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) is a good reference for this type of question.